# Алгоритмы поиска текста в файле Java

Tags: java, поиск, текст

Необходимо реализовать аналог функции Ctrl + F (Find) на Java.

Пользователь задает директорию, расширение файла и текст для поиска.

Пока я реализовал так : 1 тред непрерывно обходит директорию и если встречает файл нужного расширения - посылает задачу поиска текста в пул к свободным потокам.

Сам поиск информации я реализовал построчным чтением с помощью BufferedReader, но не учёл, перевод строки. Также, если файл будет большой (скажем, 500 мб), то поиск будет очень долгий. Есть ли какие-то алгоритмы решения данной задачи? Пока думаю, что файл нужно считывать блочно, но не понимаю как именно и по какому принципу

```
public void run() {
    Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String content = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    if (content.contains(text)) {
        systemFinderWindow.createDirectoryTree(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем обходить непрерывно?

Comment: Как вариант считать содержимое файла и при помощи регуляки найти нужное слово или текст.

Comment: Поиск однострочный или многострочный тоже доступен?

Comment: @Tskylop вопрос стоит в том как это сделать быстрее.

Comment: Поискал ответы, вроде как делать это кроме как через NIO2 API нету смысла. Теперь стоит вопрос : как разбить файл на байтовые блоки?